# How can I do horizontal flip of two views. Please, see the picture

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

There are a ViewController = VC1, and two views , view1 = "A" , view2 = "B". View "A" do horizontal flip and turns to "B".

How do I solve the problem? Please, see the picture.

[image]

Comment: do you want to flip viewA and the thing you want after flip is viewA disappeared and viewB in place of viewA?

Comment: Jaminguy has the right answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[UIView transitionFromView:view1 toView:view2 duration:1.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    completion: ^(BOOL inFinished) {
                        //do any post animation actions here
                }];
```

Comment: This flips the entire view controller. Is there a way to just flip subview A(just what's within the A box) to subview B(just what's within the B box)?